# org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString mis-interpretting UTF-8

Tags: java, url, character-encoding

I am trying to get the source from a URI. It's reported as UTF-8. I have also tried ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-1 Windows-1250 and ISO-8859-2.

Here is my code of the latest attempt (trying ISO-8859-2):

```
public static String getPage(String page,String charset) throws IOException{
        URL url=new URL(page);

        return org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(url.openConnection().getInputStream(),charset);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        String page=getPage("http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=aba","ISO-8859-2");
        System.out.println(page);
    }
```

But the result is :

*apÄ?ge* 'quita, aparta', y este del gr. á¼?Ï?Î±Î³Îµ)

instead of:

(Del lat. apăge 'quita, aparta', y este del gr. ἄπαγε).

Likewise UTF-8 (which works with other code, and in browsers) and other encoding names, also fail in a similar manner.

Comment: The entity that URI returns in your example uses UTF-8 (good for them, there's no call to be using ISO-8859-2 in this day and age, especially on the web). We can see this from the `text/html; charset=UTF-8` header. It's also in Spanish (with some Latin and some Greek in the etymology). Is this the real URI? It can't duplicate the problem to look at a UTF-8 entity.

Comment: Bye the bye. Doing a quick .NET downloader, I get (Del lat. apăge 'quita, aparta', y este del gr. ἄπαγε). if treating it as UTF-8. It's definitely UTF-8.

Comment: If I UTF-8 in Java it doesn't return the same

Comment: Sadly, I know the web and character-encoding part of this question, not the Java part. The URI you give returns perfectly good UTF-8, it's the Java bit that's wrong. (Unless you've a different URI in use, where does Romanian come into this?).

Comment: Some are spanish characters but some accents are Romanian and Greek, is there something wrong with the java code rather than the charset?

Comment: Ah, I get you. That's Latin, in modern transcriptions of Latin, `ă` means a short a (whereas in Romanian it means ə sound). Which is all very interesting, but doesn't solve anything.
Yes, it's definitely UTF-8, and certainly not any of the ISO-8859 family (the only one that has Greek letters doesn't have ă or í, and they're both there in the source). It worked fine for my .NET test, so we need to fix the title of the question, and hope someone with Java knowledge can sort it out.

Comment: Here's a question. How were you looking at the output? Could there be an encoding complication there? It's strange that you got `ÏÎ±Î³Îµ` in your ISO-8859-2 attempt, because some of those characters aren't in ISO-8859-2! Could you try your UTF-8 again, and save output to a UTF-8 text file rather than writing to the console? Maybe the code was perfect with UTF-8, but the console is letting you down.

Comment: Yes is the console, that is a funny bug, if I just take the content and display it as it is it works, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U+0103 (ă) is encoded as the byte sequence `C4 83`; this data is UTF-8.

The bug is likely due to the other transcoding operation you are performing via the `PrintStream` attached to `System.out`. This will encode the data to the [system encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29), which may be a lossy conversion and may cause corruption if the device being written to doesn't use a matching encoding.

*You can read some analysis of this with respect to the Windows console [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html).*