# Unicode Characters appearing as Question Marks in Java JSON Parsing

Tags: java, json, unicode

I have been searching about this for the past few days but I don't think I am able to find a correct pointer. Please merge it with the appropriate question if found as duplicate.

I am pretty new to working with JSON and as part of one of my projects I need to decode a JSON file and do further processing on it. However when I tried decoding using the Json-simple library, I get some weird question marks in the parsed object instead of the actual characters. A sample code is shown below:

```
String str = "{\"alias\": [\"Evr\u00f3pa\", \"\u05d0\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05e4\"]}";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)parser.parse(str);

System.out.println(jsonObject) gives {"alias":["Evrópa","?????"]}
```

I tried using Json-lib too with the same result.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: See also comments on the problems with `System.out` in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849624)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't with your JSON, it's with your System.out.println().  Those characters can't be represented in the character encoding either of your terminal (or your IDE, if that is where you ran it) or of the encoding being used by System.out in your environment.

Files can not contain Unicode characters.  Files are streams of *bytes*, but Unicode *characters* are multiple bytes (usually two) in size.  This is where character encodings become relevant.  Unicode characters must be converted to a sequence of bytes to write them to a file (including System.out).  One of the most commonly used encodings for Unicode characters is UTF-8.  The trick for software programmers is to always use the correct character encoding when converting between bytes and characters.  Lacking the correct encoding in a single place, for example in a debug println() call, will give erroneous and misleading output.

Comment: To make sure that this is not the case I already tried writing the same object I parsed, back in to a file and my unicode characters previously visible as codes in my editor are now visible as question marks in the same editor. So I guess it might be some issue with the parsing or character encoding.

Comment: Probably you didn't encode the characters correctly when you wrote them to the file, and/or your editor did not use the same encoding when reading the file.  I just quickly tested your JSON using Python (it is faster than testing with Java) and the data is fine.  It looks like characters are Hebrew, I think

Comment: Okay, I just tested it with Java (OpenJDK 1.6.0, using the libjson-simple-java library) and it worked fine.  My environment contains LANG=en_US.UTF-8; my gnome-terminal is likewise set to UTF-8.

Comment: Hi dsh, As you pointed out it is problem with the character encoding of my IDE which is set by default to the encoding of native operating system. Every thing set now. Thanks Once again.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a default character set that doesn't support the group of special characters. Try using UTF-8 as your charset, something along these lines:

```
String str = "{\"alias\": [\"Evr\u00f3pa\", \"\u05d0\u05d9\u05e8\u05d5\u05e4\"]}";
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)parser.parse(isr);
```

Comment: The data is already a string containing unicode characters.  There is no need to encode it to bytes then decode the bytes back to a string.

Comment: I feel what dsh saying is correct. Also studied some where that it can be because of our parser converting unicode encoding to some other encoding and then when the target encoding doesn't support certain characters they are converted to question marks.