# Croatian character in Java standard output

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have a database with some cratian characters in it like Đ , in the database the character is stored correctly, when using a datatable in primefaces it also shows the character in the webpage just fine.

The problem is that when I send it to the `out.println()` the character Đ in the name is missing.

```
 for (People p : people) {
     System.out.println("p.getName());
 }
```

I tried using `String name2 = p.getName().getBytes("ISO-8859-2");` but it still not working

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551962/1172714  The problem is a mismatch between the encoding you output and the encoding that whatever stdout is connected to (terminal, IDE console, etc) expects to receive.

Comment: Alexev, you say the character is stored in the database correctly, but can you tell us what encoding it is stored in?

Comment: The mysql encoding is UTF8

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using UTF-8 as default encoding on the Database and for Primefaces

Have also a look to this:

[Display special characters using System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933620/display-special-characters-using-system-out-println)